Can nginx's njs (or Lua?) be used to replace a header with that header's SHA-512?
I need to replace one log field, from nginx.conf, with its SHA-512 hash, for security reasons.  I'd prefer to do this with njs, but would consider Lua.
However, the only way I know of to modify a log field is js_set, but js_set wants synchronous code, while njs' crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-512", msgUint8) is asynchronous.
Is there an alternative to js_set that can accept an asynchronous function, that can be used in the http block of an nginx.conf?
I suspect I could use a 3rd party synchronous SHA-512 module, but we'd prefer to avoid that if possible. It'd mean more code to maintain, and a license review.
Here's a summarized version of what I have right now:
nginx.conf, in the http section:
js_import obfuscate.js;
js_set $obfuscated_token obfuscate.get_obfuscated_token_test;
log_format  main escape=json '{'
'"http_authorization":"$obfuscated_token",'
'}';


And a little test code in obfuscate.js:
async function get_obfuscated_token_test(r) {
   return "abc";
}

This replaces the http_authorization field with:
"http_authorization":"[object Promise]"

...which is not what I want.  Instead of [object Promise], I want a SHA-512 hash in hexadecimal, or at least just "abc".

This question is similar to: Is there a way to call an asynchronous function from a synchronous function in njs?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use something like:
async function get_obfuscated_token(r) {
    r.setReturnValue("abc");
}

The r.setReturnValue keeps js_set happy.
The call to js_set just looks like:
   js_path "/etc/nginx";
   js_import obfuscate.js;

   js_set $obfuscated_token obfuscate.get_obfuscated_token;

IOW, sometimes you can 'return' a value from an async function.  njs requires it sometimes too.
